# Convexity or concavity implied by an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have discovered the following fact:

Let $f(x)$ be a $C^3$ function on $[0;\infty[$ such that
$$4|f'(x)|\geq f(x)^2.$$
With a [Schwarzian derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) positive

> If $f(x)$ is negative on $[0;\infty[$, then $f(x)$ is concave.
>   If $f(x)$ is positive on $[0;\infty[$, then $f(x)$ is convex.

I have no idea to prove this and I think it's hard.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't $f(x)=-e^{-x}$ a counterexample? $f'(x)=e^{-x}$ is positive, but $f''(x)=-e^{-x}<0$, so $f$ is concave, and it satisfies the inequality.

Comment: In fact this is this : If $f(x)$ is negative on $[0;\infty[$ it implies that $f(x)$ is concave .

If $f(x)$ is positive on $[0;\infty[$ it implies that $f(x)$ is convex .

Comment: *Why* $C^3$? In the inequality we have only $f$ and $f'$...

Answer (score 1):

This is not true: Consider
$$
f(x) = -\frac1{x+1}.
$$
It is smooth, $f'= f^2$, thus $4f'\ge f^2$, $f'\ge0$, but it is not convex.

Comment: Sorry I inverse the convex and concave condition can I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + x + 2}. \quad (x \geqslant 0)
$$
On the one hand, for any $x > 0$,$$
4|f'(x)| = 4 \left| -\frac{2x + 1}{(x^2 + x + 2)^2} \right| = \frac{4(2x + 1)}{(x^2 + x + 2)^2} \geqslant \frac{1}{(x^2 + x + 2)^2} = (f(x))^2.
$$
On the other hand,$$
f''(x) = \frac{2x^2 + 2x - 3}{(x^2 + x + 2)^4},
$$
thus $f$ is not convex.

Comment: In fact the problem involves a Schwarzian derivative ($C^3$) positive wich I don't have mentionned here  .Have you a counter-example in this case ? (+1) for your interest .

Comment: @max8128 Maybe you need to rephrase the question to clearly indicate the condition and the proposition.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Now I think the problem is complete and more interesting . Unfortunately your counter-example doesn't work now. If you find a counter-example with the complet problem I accept your answer .